# Change Joomla 3 page url extension from .html to .htm

Tags: joomla

I am creating a website using Joomla 3 CMS. I have a requirement from my client that i need to change the existing page url extension from .html to .htm. As this website is redesign of a existing website the old links have .htm extension.

Answer (score 0):

Open ../libraries/cms/router/site.php
Go to line number 144
And change

if ($format = $uri->getVar('format', 'html'))

to

if ($format = $uri->getVar('format', 'htm'))

I hope that helps

Comment: Hey i did what you said. But refreshing the site if i click on any page, the url is proper with .htm extension but no page content is displayed. Following is the error i get 404
View not found [name, type, prefix]: article, htm, contentView
The Page you are looking for doesn't exist or an other error occurred. Go back, or head over to Home Page to choose a new direction.
You may not be able to visit this page because of:
an out-of-date bookmark/favourite

Comment: The whole point of that line is that it is setting the default to `html` but you override the default in the UI for global configuration. As soon as you update this change would be lost .. not to mention that it will still be overridden by what is saved in global configuration.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to edit core files, and that is certainly not advised for sake of future upgrades. Your best solution is using a custom component for managing Joomla's SEF URLs, for example: sh404SEF (Paid) or JoomSEF (Free).

Check out http://extensions.joomla.org/category/site-management/sef for others.

Answer (score 0):

Never ever edit Joomla Core files, otherwise when you upgrade Joomla, all your changes will be gone.

As @Alexxandar said; use SEO/SEF components for your needs. I recommend to use [MijoSEF](http://miwisoft.com/joomla-extensions/mijosef-joomla-seo-sef-urls#pricing) (Free or Paid)

Comment: I installed MijoSEF ok. After i installed the original had menu item alias(without article alias) with .html extension..but now i am getting as http://safehandindia.com/orgch/consulting-assessments-facilitation-and-workshops which has article page alias but without any extension.  I am ok with this but i need a .htm extension. In its configuration i have put .htm beside URL suffix parameter. what else to be done? Any link to its tutorial as to how to use this extension ?

Comment: burakcakirel Any suggestions?

Comment: I installed it on my local and configure it as ".htm" and it works.
@Pooja

Comment: Thank you burakcakirel. I reinstalled a fresh copy of the extension. And it works absolutely fine. But now 2 issues are there:  one is initially i had made few changes to get rid of index.php file. Now I am unable to get it back. If i rename that .htaccess to htaccess.txt the other pages with .htm show 404 error.  I want index.php too index.htm along with other pages. Does it work for you?

Comment: Hello @burakcakirel. need help help on above issue.

Answer (score 0):

Go to global configuration and remove the l from the suffix.
THis is a Joomla configuration question and a standard joomla configuration (not programming) option.

Now the one thing you will have to worry about is that if there are any old links to the htm pages.  FOr this you will probably want to use the built in redirect component.  Turn on the redirect plugin and then if you have a small number of pages you can just set up the redirection by hand. If you have more pages you may want to write the sql to create a bunch of redirects. Or you might want to make your own plugin to permanently redirect the old to the new.